# Hybrid 'Discrete triangular number base' numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-number-theory

I'm trying to invent a new type of number who's digits are composed of hybrid 'Discrete Triangular Number Base' numbers (Which have two components; one in 'Discrete Triangular Number Base X and Base Y' and the other in Base 1)

Some examples are:

`Base X = 4 and Base Y = 2
Generating Hybrid Triangle Base Numbers [Triangle Base 4] and [Base 2] in [Base 1] numbers 0 to 10
NUMBER  [4 3 2 1] [4 3 2 1]             TRIANGLE BASE NUMBER
;       [1 1 1 1] [1 1 1 1]
0       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]             0:0
1       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 1]             0:1
2       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 1 1]             0:2
3       [0 0 0 0] [0 1 1 1]             0:3
4       [0 0 0 0] [1 0 0 0]             4:0
5       [0 0 0 0] [1 0 0 1]             4:1
6       [0 0 0 0] [1 0 1 1]             4:2
7       [0 0 0 0] [1 1 0 0]             7:0
8       [0 0 0 0] [1 1 0 1]             7:1
9       [0 0 0 0] [1 1 1 0]             9:0
10      [0 0 0 1] [0 0 0 0]             0:1|0:0
FINISHED GENERATING NUMBERS`

`Base X = 4 and Base Y = 3
Generating Hybrid Triangle Base Numbers [Triangle Base 4] and [Base 3] in [Base 1] numbers 0 to 20
NUMBER  [4 3 2 1] [4 3 2 1]             TRIANGLE BASE NUMBER
;       [1 1 1 1] [1 1 1 1]
0       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]             0:0
1       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 1]             0:1
2       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 2]             0:2
3       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 1 2]             0:3
4       [0 0 0 0] [0 0 2 2]             0:4
5       [0 0 0 0] [0 1 2 2]             0:5
6       [0 0 0 0] [0 2 2 2]             0:6
7       [0 0 0 0] [1 2 2 2]             0:7
8       [0 0 0 0] [2 0 0 0]             8:0
9       [0 0 0 0] [2 0 0 1]             8:1
10      [0 0 0 0] [2 0 0 2]             8:2
11      [0 0 0 0] [2 0 1 2]             8:3
12      [0 0 0 0] [2 0 2 2]             8:4
13      [0 0 0 0] [2 1 2 2]             8:5
14      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 0 0]             14:0
15      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 0 1]             14:1
16      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 0 2]             14:2
17      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 1 2]             14:3
18      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 2 0]             18:0
19      [0 0 0 0] [2 2 2 1]             18:1
20      [0 0 0 1] [0 0 0 0]             0:1|0:0
FINISHED GENERATING NUMBERS`

My current progress is trying to figure out how the second component can be represented in Base 2

https://pastebin.com/p6S7G0Bw

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what a "Discrete Triangular Number" is?  For example, it seems like you have code that enumerates them; can you summarize how your code does that?

Comment: a discrete triangular number base is a number that's composed of a tianglular number base y

ie: triangular number base 4 has digits composed if triangluar number base 4 numbers

https://pastebin.com/6cN82xRy